# Subset of list in Dataframe R in categorical variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

My data looks like that but number of observations are approx 10000.

```
Part<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Disease_codes>-c("A101.12","A111.12","A121.13","A130.0","B102","C132","D156")
class(Disease_codes)<-Factor

df<-data.frame(Part,Disease_codes)
```

The obs having Disease_codes starting from  `A10_A13` are `BloodCancer` patients. I need to make subset of it and i am trying following

```
BloodCancer <- subset(df, grepl('^A10', Disease_codes), select = Part

Part_without_Blood_cancer <- subset(df, !grepl('^A10', Disease_codes))
```

If i am trying the following it is not working.

```
BloodCancer <- subset(df, grepl('^A10-A13', Disease_codes), select = Part
```

But it is giving me just A10 coding containing Participants but I want `BloodCancer` variable to contain all from `A10-A13`. How can i do this in one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for grepl to return true for any of the strings (e.g. A10, A11) is as follows:
grepl("A10| A11", variable). To keep it as one statement, you can do the following:

```
BloodCancer = subset(df, grepl(paste(paste("A1", 0:3, sep = ""), collapse = "|"), Disease_codes), select = Part)
```

Comment: I dnt want A14 to be included in BloodCancer. Will the above command just include A10 to A13 ?

Comment: yes, provided that the letter can only be at the beginning of the code (that there cannot be A14.0A10 for example, which I presume is so since you are using grepl). Then it looks for any strings which include A10 or  A11 or A12 or A13 which is done through pasting A1 and then 0, 1, 2, 3 in the first subbracket

Comment: welcome! saw the comment earlier about select - I edited the answer to include select if anything (also there was a pair of extra brackets around grepl), but it is the same place where you had it orginally :)

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```
BloodCancer <- subset(df, grepl("^A1[0-3]", as.character(Disease_codes)), select = Part)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Disease_codes, "^A1[0-3]")) %>%
  select(Part)
```